# Given an array of integers and an integer n, how to find a subarray (non contiguous) that sums to n?

Tags: java, arrays

I'm doing an exercise and I'm stuck to check if there is a way to find a non contiguous sequence inside a sorted array that sums to a given integer n.

For example:

```
    int[] a = {1, 2, 4, 5, 10};
    int n = 20;
```

Integers that sum to 20 are in positions 0, 2, 3, 4.

How can I do that?

Comment: How do you know there is such a sequence?

Comment: Is the array assumed to be sorted?

Comment: @FrankPuffer Yes, it is sorted

Answer (score 0):

You should iterate over all subsets of a set.
For set with N you can have `Math.pow(2,N)` subsets. And for this you could iterate from 1 to `Math.pow(2,N)` and try to some up elements of those position where bit value is 1, and if the subset sums to K, than you found the subset.